# Database Structure for 1-many-many

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-schema

I need some ideas how to handle the database structure for a site i'm working on, i have been whacking my brains over it for a while to figure out the best way to design the tables to help it become scalable. Here are the details.

- Listing: A single post with title text, post date and simple other info. Will Connect with user table to get username.
- Tags: Each listing can have several tags belonging to a 'type' Example:

  Genre: Action, Supernatural, Comedy

  Producers: Sunrise, Bones
- Extra Fields: Each listing can have extra fields too Example:

  Air Dates: 18th Dec 2010

  Duration: 120 mins

The Normalized way would be something like:

-- Listing_table (list_id, user_id, list_title, list_content, list_date)

-- Tags_table (tag_id, tag_type, tag_name, tag_slug)

-- Tags_Listing_table (list_id, tag_id)

-- Field_table (list_id, field_name, field_value)

Would this structure be fine ? Also what would be the best way to query all this information efficiently. I don't think its possible at all to get all this in one query. what are my options?

Also each listing will load multiple threads and inside those threads will be multiple posts, all on the same page kinda like:

[SINGLE PAGE]

Listing (title, content, tags, extra fields)

- Thread 1

  - Post 1
  - Post 2
- Thread 2

  - Post 1
  - Post 2

Thanks for everyone who helps, I really would appreciate some insight you all. If there is anything further I can add to help you help me please ask. I can dump my SQL structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you're aiming for scalability or performance, you'll almost certainly regret this:

```
-- Field_table (list_id, field_name, field_value)
```

For some of the specific reasons, see [SQL Antipatterns Strike Back](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back). This structure starts on slide 16. Also read [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/), which has to do with both scalability and performance.

Comment: What is wrong with it? and how can it be improved? Also Wordpress uses similar for its custom fields. Thanks for your input.

Comment: a) You can't rely on attribute names. One user might enter "created"; others might enter "created_on", "date_created", or even "new on". b) Skilled database administrators are hard to find; this makes every casual user your database administrator. c) Data types and domains can't help you. One user enters {'date_created, '2011-01-01'}; another enters {'date_created', 'yesterday'}. d) Reconstructing a row requires one join per attribute. e) Every constraint must be implemented correctly in every application. You have almost no chance of getting that right every time in every application.

Comment: Hmm well maybe if

a) if the field name is pre-decided and st in the PHP itself it will alwyas be the same. 

b) yeah db admins are hard to find

c) Javascript date system can be used for that so its always a specific format for the field Or converted to timestamp

d) yes that's where the problem is =[ any solution to handle it?

e) true but what are the alternative ways of handling it ?

Comment: If "field name" is "pre-decided", why isn't it a column in a table? If it's restricted by PHP, can users create new field names? I don't have Javascript enabled. How do you know an arbitrary "field name" requires a timestamp instead of a string or an integer? Will you restrict the values of "field name" to one language? How will you prevent me from using "Erstellungsdatum" for a "field name" value? Build a proper data model, and put all the known constraints in the database, not in the application. Let the dbms do what it excels at, so you can concentrate on what you excel at.

Comment: @Catcall: Thanks for your advice i appreciate it, and i think i will follow one of the designs from the link you provided, you are right, since I have a few fields it best to make them columns then rows. Do you have any advice regarding the tagging problem? since it has several tags for a field.

Comment: @DregondRahl: You already have a table of tags that can limit which tags are used, and you already have a table to handle the many-to-many relationship between tags and lists. So you don't have a tagging problem. Unless you know something I don't. (Always possible.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a typical [entity-attribute-value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model) approach.  This model is fine, especially for high traffic websites, but it does not lend itself well to SQL.  Instead of:

```
select * from Listing_table where postdate > '2011-02-01'
```

You'll find yourself writing queries like:

```
select  *
from    Listing_table lt 
where   (select value from field_table ft where lt.list_id = ft.list id 
         and field_name = 'postdate') > '2011-02-01'
```

And that's just for a simple date compare. This gets complex really really fast.

Basically, EAV is a tradeoff where you use the database mostly for persistant storage and less for logic and report generation.

Comment: The listing table itself has postdate (list_date) the fields table only has values that won't be searched for such as run time of the TVshow or the date it was originally started airing. Those fields won't be searched. The thing is the fields aren't the same for every listing that's why I separated it otherwise there will be NULL rows.